# Viewing all defined variables

Tags: python, variables

I'm currently working on a computation in python shell. What I want to have is Matlab style listout where you can see all the variables that have been defined up to a point (so I know which names I've used, their values and such).

Is there a way, and how can I do that?

Comment: I'm dimensioning some structure by the rules of a classification society. So all the thicknesses are t, lengths L etc. And sometimes they call each other, so the t used in chap.7.2.4. uses t from 3.2.2. Its a one-time computation, so I just use py as a interactive shell.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning: Spyder has an excellent variable explorer that might be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 490):

A few things you could use:

- `dir()` will give you the list of in-scope variables
- `globals()` will give you a dictionary of global variables
- `locals()` will give you a dictionary of local variables

Comment: [Helpful link describing these in further detail...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars.)

Comment: When I run `globals()` or `print(globals())`. I get `TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type NoneType)` Any idea why?

Comment: I think this will happen if there is a global variable defined that implements the __repr__ method incorrectly (ie doesn't return a string).

Answer (score 313):

If possible, you may want to use [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/).

To get a list of all current user-defined variables, IPython provides a *magic command* named `who` (magics must be prefixed with the `%` character unless the `automagic` feature is enabled):

```
In [1]: foo = 'bar'
In [2]: %who
foo
```

You can use the `whos` magic to get more detail:

```
In [3]: %whos
Variable   Type    Data/Info
----------------------------
foo        str     bar
```

There are a wealth of other magics available. IPython is basically the Python interpreter on steroids. One convenient magic is `store`, which lets you save variables between sessions (using `pickle`).

Note: I am not associated with IPython Dev - just a satisfied user.

Edit:

You can find all the magic commands in the [IPython Documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).

[This article](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/) also has a helpful section on the use of magic commands in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: to clarify, pickle is available as a regular package outside of IPython too. Very useful!

Answer (score 58):

To get the names:

```
for name in vars().keys():
  print(name)
```

To get the values:

```
for value in vars().values():
  print(value)
```

vars() also takes an optional argument to find out which vars are defined within an object itself.

Comment: python generate new vars inside loop and cannot execute your expressions cause: "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration". I have to store vars() in temporary variable and after that print them out

Comment: This specific code worked for me in Python 3.9.6 and avoids the "Runtime dictionary changed size" error.  


`# this is Егор Волков's tip`

`tmp_vars = vars().keys()`

`# I think 'name' has to be initialized to avoid the error too`

`name = "anything"`

`for name in tmp_vars:`

    `print("var=[%s] mem_usage=[%.4f]" % (name, sys.getsizeof(eval(name) ) ))`

Sorry about the formatting.

Answer (score 54):

As RedBlueThing and analog said:

- `dir()` gives a list of in scope variables
- `globals()` gives a dictionary of global variables
- `locals()` gives a dictionary of local variables

Using the interactive shell (version 2.6.9), after creating variables `a = 1` and `b = 2`, running `dir()` gives

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a', 'b']
```

running `locals()` gives

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

Running `globals()` gives exactly the same answer as `locals()` in this case.

I haven't gotten into any modules, so all the variables are available as both local and global variables.  `locals()` and `globals()` list the values of the variables as well as the names; `dir()` only lists the names.

If I import a module and run `locals()` or `globals()` inside the module, `dir()` still gives only a small number of variables; it adds `__file__` to the variables listed above. `locals()` and `globals()` also list the same variables, but in the process of printing out the dictionary value for `__builtin__`, it lists a far larger number of variables: built-in functions, exceptions, and types such as "`'type': <type 'type'>`", rather than just the brief `<module '__builtin__' (built-in)>` as shown above.

For more about `dir()` see [Python 2.7 quick reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/dir-function.html) at New Mexico Tech or [the dir() function](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/dir.html) at ibiblio.org.

For more about `locals()` and `globals()` see [locals and globals](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html) at Dive Into Python and a page about [globals](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/globals-function.html) at New Mexico Tech.

[Comment:  @Kurt:  You gave a link to [enumerate-or-list-all-variables-in-a-program-of-your-favorite-language-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430811/enumerate-or-list-all-variables-in-a-program-of-your-favorite-language-here) but that answer has a mistake in it. The problem there is:  `type(name)` in that example will always return `<type 'str'>`. You do get a list of the variables, which answers the question, but with incorrect types listed beside them.  This was not obvious in your example because all the variables happened to be strings anyway; however, what it's returning is the type of the name of the variable instead of the type of the variable.  To fix this: instead of `print type(name)` use `print eval('type(' + name + ')')`. I apologize for posting a comment in the answer section but I don't have comment posting privileges, and the other question is closed.]

Answer (score 20):

print locals()

edit continued from comment.

To make it look a little prettier when printing:

```
import sys, pprint
sys.displayhook = pprint.pprint
locals()
```

That should give you a more vertical printout.

Comment: or form pprint import pprint, then use pprint instead of print

Answer (score 17):

`globals()`, `locals()`, `vars()`, and `dir()` may all help you in what you want.

Answer (score 16):

a bit more smart (python 3) way:

```
def printvars():

   tmp = globals().copy()
   [print(k,'  :  ',v,' type:' , type(v)) for k,v in tmp.items() if not k.startswith('_') and k!='tmp' and k!='In' and k!='Out' and not hasattr(v, '__call__')]
```

Or if you wannt to output the variables of an object:

```
def printObj(Obj, OutputMax=100):

   tmp = Obj.__dict__
   [print(k,'  :  ',str(v)[:OutputMax],' type:' , type(v)) for k,v in tmp.items() if not k.startswith('_') and k!='tmp' and k!='In' and k!='Out' and not hasattr(v, '__call__')]
```

Answer (score 12):

keep in mind dir() will return all current imports, **AND** variables.

if you just want your variables, I would suggest a naming scheme that is easy to extract from dir, such as varScore, varNames, etc.

that way, you can simply do this:

```
for vars in dir():
 if vars.startswith("var"):
   print vars
```

**Edit**

if you want to list all variables, but exclude imported modules and variables such as:

```
__builtins__
```

you can use something like so:

```
import os
import re

x = 11
imports = "os","re"

for vars in dir():
    if vars.startswith("__") == 0 and vars not in imports:
        print vars
```

as you can see, it will show the variable "imports" though, because it is a variable (well, a tuple). A quick workaround is to add the word "imports" into the imports tuple itself!

Comment: Uhmm, no, that won't be possible I'm afraid. Most of them are just t, a, c, d, L, p ... and such.

Answer (score 10):

This has to be defined in the interactive shell:

```
def MyWho():
    print([v for v in globals().keys() if not v.startswith('_')])
```

Then the following code can be used as an example:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> a = 10 
>>> MyWho()
['a', 'MyWho', 'sys', 'os']
```

Answer (score 5):

In my Python 2.7 interpreter, the same `whos` command that exists in MATLAB exists in Python. It shows the same details as the MATLAB analog (variable name, type, and value/data).

Note that in the Python interpreter, `whos` lists all variables in the "interactive namespace".

Comment: `whos` is actually an **I**Python magic function `%whos`. The "plain" Python interpreter has no such function AFAIK.