# Python IDLE - is there any IDLE feature to edit previously defined classes/functions?

Tags: python, python-idle

Im using IDLE as a python shell and i declare a class, ie:

```
>>> class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, model, year):
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
```

after a while (and a lot of code...) i want to check that class definition. Is there any COMMAND that i can see the class Car definition ?

can i re-edit it (in IDLE)?

Comment: You could print `locals()` or `globals()`.

Comment: These kinds of features aren't immediately visible in IDLE (short of calling `locals()` and `globals()` types of functions). You should select [a more fully-featured IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) if you want those kinds of things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Viewing all defined variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but i think i didnt explain myself very well - so i re-edit the question.

Comment: @CoryKramer Please do not post disinformation.  There are 2 ways to see and edit previous input.

Answer (score 0):

In console - see [The Python Tutorial - Modules - The dir() Function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#the-dir-function).

<s>For the file open in IDLE - `File->Class Browser`.</s> whoops, it only shows functions and classes, not global variables

Answer (score 0):

Method 1. Use the 'history-previous' key, which defaults to Alt-P ('history-next' is Alt-N, replace 'Alt' with 'Control' for Mac).  It retrieves previous *statements* in the history list.  (Some consoles, including that on Windows, only retrieve physical lines.)  This is described in the IDLE Help document under Python Shell Window - Command History.  Your example:

```
>>> class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, model, year):
        self.model=model
        self.year=year

>>> a = 2
>>> class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, model, year):
        self._model=model
        self._year=year

>>>
```

I retrieved the class definition by hitting Alt-P twice.  After finishing editing, make sure to move the cursor to the end before hitting `Enter`.

Method 2. Scroll back up, select the text you want copied (it need not be a complete statement), hit `Enter`, and the selected text will be copied to the current input line.