# Equivalent of R ls() but ONLY for user generated objects / functions?

Tags: python

This has been asked multiple times here but I can only find references to `dir()`, which lists *all* names in the current scope. This is overkill and I'm looking for a way to ONLY list the objects in the scope that have been generated by the user in this session, instead of all objects / functions available in the environment.

Comment: Take a look at the [second answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/634581/2588818). I don't think there is a general way to do what you're saying in Python, but some IDEs and iPython (an enhanced REPL) do this.

Comment: Thanks I had missed that thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else ever reads this: `whos` is as close as I could get. It displays a list of user-generated variables *and* modules imported, and displays a few attributes too. Not as clean as `ls()` in R but some people might find this useful. Works better than `dir()` for sure.

Comment: Note - use whos rather than whos().  Why is this?