# Printing a list as variable values

Tags: python, variables, reflection

How would I print a list of strings as their individual variable values?

For example, take this code:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
text="abc"
splittext = text.split(text)
print(splittext)
```

How would I get this to output `123`?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't; you'd use a dict for this.

Comment: You should think about your problem before you ask for copy/paste code.

Comment: text is just used as a generic variable name. This is just a sample code

Comment: see if [this SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables) can point you in the right direction

Comment: This sounds like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/132201) problem. What are you _really_ trying to accomplish? There are no doubt better ways to do what you want then to create a string composed of variable names.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using `eval`, but it is **very dangerous**:

```
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x : str(eval(x)),Text))
'123'
```

`eval` (perhaps they better rename it to `evil`, no hard feelings, simply use it as a warning) evaluates a string as if you would have coded it there yourself. So `eval('a')` will fetch the value of `a`. The problem is that a hacker could perhaps find some trick to inject arbitrary code using this, and thus hack your server, program, etc. Furthermore by accident it can perhaps change the state of your program. So a piece of advice is "*Do not use it, unless you have absolutely no other choice*" (which is not the case here).

Or a less dangerous variant:

```
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x : str(globals()[x]),Text))
'123'
```

in case these are **global** variables (you can use `locals()` for local variables).

This is *ugly* and dangerous, because you do not know in advance what `a`, `b` and `c` are, neither do you have much control on what part of the program can set these variables. So it can perhaps allow code injection. As is advertised in the comments on your question, you better use a dictionary for that.

## Dictionary approach

A better way to do this is using a dictionary (as @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams was saying):

```
>>> dic = {'a':1,'b': 2,'c':3}
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x : str(dic[x]),Text))
'123'
```

## List instead of string

In the above we converted the content to a string using `str` in the lambda-expression and used `''.join` to concatenate these strings. If you are however interested in an array of "results", you can drop these constructs. For instance:

```
>>> map(lambda x : dic[x],Text)
[1, 2, 3]
```

The same works for all the above examples.

**EDIT**

For some reason, I later catched the fact that you want to *print* the valuesm, this can easily be achieved using [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
for x in Text :
    print dic[x]
```

again you can use the same technique for the above cases.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to print out the value of the variables named in the string you can use `locals` (or `globals`, depending on what/where you want them)

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=2
>>> c=3
>>> s='abc'
>>> for v in s:
...  print(locals()[v])
... 
1
2
3
```

or, if you use separators in the string

```
>>> s='a,b,c'
>>> for v in s.split(','):
...  print(locals()[v])
... 
1
2
3
```