# Print variables in current namespace in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

Is there an ipython magic command that will print the variables in the current namespace?

[The ipython documentation is here](http://ipython.org/documentation.html) and I don't see an answer to this.

[A list of magic commands in ipython is here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Viewing all defined variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables)

Comment: @Ashafix not really, that's a python question, the only ipython answer is buried deep. If there's a better ipython answer it would need to go on a question about ipython.

Comment: Just learned something new, when you flag it by linking to an answer, SO links to the question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/634581/2776376

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how this question could be improved. Maybe somebody is upset it's a duplicate (which is only partly true) [even though we explicitly encourage having duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32315/183887).

Comment: `who` and `whos` give a summary of the variables, but not necessarily their full values.  That's especially true with complex items like numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

It's answered in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/634581/1339987

The command is `who`. Here is some sample code:

```
In [9]: who
```

You can also use `whos` for more detail, like this:

```
In [10]: whos
```

Comment: If the answer to a question is the same as another question, mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @MattDMo no, there's probably a better ipython solution and it wouldn't get posted on the source question about python. Duplicates aren't perfect.