# Print name of variable and value in ipython notebook concisely

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'd like to print all the variables and their values defined in a cell without having to do

```
print('x:', x)
print('y:', y)
print('z:', z)
```

...
is there something like:
     `%p x y z`
and it will do the equivalent of the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a line magic which will do that.Something like below

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic
@register_line_magic
def p(args):
    for key in args.split(" "):
        print globals()[key]
```

Comment: This actually answers the OP's question. Just to make it work in Python 3 and to print the variable name as well, I changed the last line to `print(key,": ", globals()[key])`

Answer (score 1):

With ipython notebook you can use:

```
#without turning on %automagic
%who
#with turning on %automagic
who
```

This will display all variables names held in memory

```
#without turning on %automagic
%whos
#with turning on %automagic
whos
```

This will display variable names and their values

References:

[iPython Magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

[Relevant StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'test1'
y = 'test2'
z = 'test3'

print('x: %s, y: %s, z: %s'%(x, y,z))
```

if x, y, z variables is integers, You should use %d instead of %s.