# How do I get the toplevel variable list of python's top-level program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance, when I run in a python's top-level program file, I can use __name__ 
  to get the string "__main__",  but how do I get the current list of toplevel global variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this thread: [Viewing all defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables)

Quoting the best answer:

> `dir()` will give you the list of in scope variables
>
> `globals()` will give you a dictionary of global variables
>
> `locals()` will give you a dictionary of local variables

Comment: In the future, please vote to close as a duplicate, don't copy and paste another answer!