# If a variable exists, then do this in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically trying to get an if else statement to work so that my data frame which is inside of a for loop gets updated (appended) with a new entry each time the for loop runs

psuedo code:

```
if df does not exist
   df = some matrix
else
   df1 = some new matrix
   df1 = df1.append(df)
```

it just doesnt work; i think i have the wrong syntax

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code so that we can see a clearer picture of what is happening? Also please share the output you're getting as your pseudo code doesn't help much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Viewing all defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables)

Comment: Are you checking if the variable named `df` literally exists at all, or are you checking if it has a non-empty value?  i.e. in real life it would be the difference between an empty box, and no box at all.

Comment: Inside a function, if `df` is an optional arg, declare it in the function header as `def myfunc(required_args_go_here, ..., df=None)`

Answer (score 1):

If the variable named `df` literally does not exist, then this code will not work.

Initialize `df` to some empty value at the beginning of your code, then check if it's empty:

```
df = None

... lots of code here, that possibly assigns df a value

if df:
    do_something(df)

else:
    df = something_else()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a colon(:) after if and else statement

```py
if not df:
   df = some matrix
else:
   df1 = some new matrix
   df1 = df1.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set df to something to use it as a name in your if statement. Sensible empty values are `None` and a dataframe with no rows. Let's assume the first.

```py
import pandas

df = None

for i in range(100):
    if df is None:
        # Your default dataframe here.
        # You probably want to set column names and types.
        df = pandas.DataFrame()

    # Instead of appending i, append your row.
    df = df.append([i])
```

But then, you could obviously raise the if statement out of the for loop, which makes more sense.