# How to get all the local variables defined inside the function in python?

Tags: python, function, local-variables

Is there any way to print all the local variables without printing them expilictly ?

```
def some_function(a,b):
    name='mike'
    city='new york'

    #here print all the local variables inside this function?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewing all defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables)

Comment: @Countour-Integral No, my question specific to the function variables. The below answer satisfies my question.

Comment: The very first and at least half of the answers there, mention how to get local variables despite the more generilized title. It does indeed answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

That would be the [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) built-in function

```
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> locals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>}
>>> x = 5
>>> locals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'x': 5}
```

You can filter out the builtins with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [_ for _ in locals() if not (_.startswith('__') and _.endswith('__'))]
['x']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want variable names you can use dir() as well:

```
def some_function(a, b):
    name='Mike'
    city='New York'

    # print all the local variables inside this function?
    print(dir())
some_function('a', 'b')
```