# Return global and local variables and their values from python code

Tags: python, debugging

At work, I was given a task to return all global and local variables and their values from the given python code. I tried to do that with a debugger but I don't have enough knowledge and couldn't find sources of how to do that. What can you suggest or maybe you had some similar issue?

I need to write a program that takes as input a python code and returns (in the dictionary, stack, anyway) all local and global variables and their values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewing all defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dir()` function while debugging, it will output any existing name in the environment.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to write new debuggers. Like I need to write class Bdb and then constructor? Is there any example of that?

Comment: Actually it is not needed to use it in debugging. You can print the output in any part of your code. I don't know your exact use case.

Comment: I need to write program which takes as input a python code and returns variables and their values.

Comment: As a string? So without running the code?

Comment: In any way and I don't know if the program can run the code by itself. If it can then it's okay

Comment: If it is a trusted program, you can read the content, append "print(dir())" and eval the string.