# Is there a way to observe created variables in Google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I can find a way to observe the variables that I have created without using print()

Comment: In the case that you're simply wondering how you can view defined variables in Python, check out [Viewing all defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables) and [..difference between globals(), locals(), and vars()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969949/whats-the-difference-between-globals-locals-and-vars.).